# $x^3+ax+b=0$ has only one solution

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$. Show that there exists only one $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $x^3+ax+b=0$.

Is it possible to prove this using the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative of the function is $3x^2+a$, Since the derivative is always positive the function is increasing and thus injective.

So it cannot repeat values, in particular it cannot have two roots.

Answer (score 9):

Since $f'(x)>0$ the given function is increasing, hence injective.
 
A cubic polynomial always has a real root, hence the claim is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, the discriminant of a reduced cubic $x^3 + ax + b$ is $-4a^3 - 27b^2$, hence negative in this case. So from the three roots, two are complex conjugates and one is real (there is *always* at least one real root for a cubic with real coefficients).

Answer (score 3):

let $f(x) = x^3 + ax+b$.

- **Existence**
  Since $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = \pm\infty$ and $f(x)$ is continuous. By IVT, $f(x) = 0$ has at least one real root.
- **Uniqueness**
  For any $x > y$, we have
  $$\begin{align}f(x)-f(y) &= (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2 + a)\\
  &= (x-y)\left(\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2 + \frac34 y^2 + a\right)\\
  &\ge a(x-y) > 0
  \end{align}
  $$
  So $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and $f(x) = 0$ has at most one real root.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative approach is using [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs).

Case $1: b =0 $. Then clearly the equation has exactly one real root, namely $0$.

Case $2: b \neq 0$. As the degree of equation is odd therefore there exists at least one real root, say $x$. Suppose it has another real root $y \neq x$.

Then $$x^3 + ax + b=0 \\y^3+ay + b=0$$ This gives $$x^3 - y^3 +a(x-y) =0$$ This implies $x^2+y^2 +xy+a=0.$ This gives $$xy= -(x^2+y^2+a) <0$$ Thus $x$ and $y$ have different signs. Without loss of generality assume $x>0, y<0$.

Thus the equation has at least one positive and one negative root. Applying descartes rule of signs this gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using Rolle's Theorem is as follows:  Suppose $x^3+ax+b = 0$ has more than one real solution.  Call the solutions $a$ and $b$.  Then by Rolle's Theorem we know that $3x^2+a = 0$ for some $c$ in $(a,b)$, but with $a>0$ this is impossible.  Hence $x^3+ax+b$ cannot have more than one real solution.

Comment: (+1) Rolle's theorem is the standard approach for this kind of questions. So it is good there is atleast one answer using it.